# Update Parent UpdatePanel from Child UpdatePanel - Conditionally

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, updatepanel, nested

I am trying to trying to setup an updatepanel to update every X seconds, the problem is I don't want the control to actually refresh unless there is new data.  So I currently have a child updatepanel in a parent UpdatePanel, the child updatepanel gets refreshed by a timer.  But I can't seem to find a way to trigger the parent panel to update.  Again, only when certain conditions(data changed) are met.

Sample Code:

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" runat="server" Interval="10000"></asp:Timer>
<asp:updatepanel id="upParent" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>    
        <asp:Label id="lblParenttime" Runat="server">Parent Time Here</asp:Label>     
        <asp:updatepanel id="upChild" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label id="lblChildtime" Runat="server">Child Time Here</asp:Label>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
            </triggers> 
        </asp:updatepanel>  
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:updatepanel>  

Protected Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
   lblChildtime.Text = Now.Tostring
   if X = Y then
       'Cause Parent to Update
       lblParenttime.Text = Now.Tostring
   end if     
End Sub
```

Comment: @dotnetrob I have never run into a scenario where I needed to have an `UpdatePanel` in another `UpdatePanel`.  My answer might help but I think you should consider if there is a better way of approaching this to not have to have one embedded in the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger some javascript when you `UpdatePanel` refreshes with the following javascript code:

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_pageLoaded(YourJavascriptFunctionNameHere);
```

You could then put a hidden button on the other `UpdatePanel` and manually call the `__DoPostBack` from the javascript function you have hooked onto the `UpdatePanel` reload.

There is probably other ideas for how to leverage `add_pageLoaded` in your scenario but this should at least get you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `upParent.Update()` in the Timer1_Tick event when conditions are met ?